# Setup .htaccess to read static folder from a main subfolder instead the public_html

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

I decided to change my react-app files to be at the subfolder `public_html/main/` *--for git automation reasons--*, then I also made some changes in my `.htaccess` file so it can read the main folder.

Now, reading the `main/index.html` is working fine, although the `.htaccess` is not detecting `static/` inside `main`, instead is looking for it in `public_html/` (I know it because when I put static there it worked). And I need to change in some way this dot file to read static in the subfolder.

I have the next folder tree structure at my server:

```
public_html/
  .htaccess
  main/
    index.html
    static/
      css/
      js/
      media/
```

While `.htaccess` looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?udecursos.study$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?udecursos.study$

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, when I knew that you can have a `.htaccess` file in both folders, the root and the sub one. When the dot file in the subfolder will override the others `.htaccess`.

So I configured the root (`public_html/`) `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?udecursos.study$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?udecursos.study$
```

While in the subfolder with location `public_html/main/` the `.htaccess` ended
up like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Actually working and reading the needed files.

Comment: Your `/main/.htaccess` file is rewriting requests back to `/index.html` (in the document root)... but from your file structure `index.html` is located inside the `/main` subdirectory?

Comment: Indeed @MrWhite the `index.html` is inside the `/main` folder. 
Following the structure as follows:

`public_html/main/`
`public_html/.htaccess`

, while inside the `/main`:

`main/.htaccess`
`main/index.html`

Comment: "Indeed @MrWhite the `index.html` is inside the `/main` folder." - But that's not what the directives would call in your answer. Your rule rewrites requests to `/index.html` (in the document root), not `/main/index.html` in the subdirectory. (?)

Comment: You must be right; I'm new to this sort of configurations while setting a web-app, I literally stopped touching my code when it started to work as needed for this case.